# Print the contents of a 2D vector using auto

Tags: c++, vector, 2d, auto

I have the vector of vectors `a`, and I want to print out the contents of the first vector.

```
a = [ 1 5 3 ; 11 17 14 ]
```

knowing it's size/dimension, I could do that using the following:

```
for ( int k = 0; k <= a[0].size(); k++)
    cout << a[0][k] << endl;
```

and the output, as I wanted it, is:

```
1 5 3
```

However, in another example where the vector changes its size during execution, I tried to use the following:

```
for ( auto k : a[0])
    cout << a[0][k] << endl;
```

but the output is as the following:

```
5 0
```

How can I get the elements of the first vector using the `auto` keyword without knowing the dimensions of the vector?

Comment: I do believe when you use `for ( auto k : a[0] )`, `k` is being assigned to the first element in the vector, a[0] which is 1. Therefore, a[0][k] returns a[0][1] which is 5. Moving forward, a[0][5] is 0 (out of range), and a[0][3] is also 0 (out of range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `auto` keyword, `k` is being assigned to the *value* of each element in the vector, not the index of the element. Therefore, if you wanted to print out the contents of the array, print out just k:

```
for ( auto k : a[0] )
    cout << k << endl;
```

EDIT: For clarity, the reason it works in the first for loop is because you are setting k to be every integer from 0 to the number of elements in a[0], and therefore the index of each element, rather than the value.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solved it partially, since now it's giving [1 5], but missing the last element of the vector. How can I print all the elements?

Comment: I could have done that using `cout << a[0][a[0].size()]` after the for loop, but would prefer if there is more automatic way to do it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be if you're initializing your vector as a vector of 2-elements. Can you post your initialization code?

Comment: well for this very simple example I just used the following `vector < int > b(2,0);
    vector < vector <int> > a(3, b);` but in the original code it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: My apologies for the delay. The problem is with your initialization. When you initialize vector `b`, you're declaring it as a vector of 2 elements, both with value 0. You're then initializing `a` to be a vector of 3 elements, each with value `b`. Therefore you're ending up with this structure : `a = [ [0,0], [0,0], [0,0] ]`. If you look at just a[0], you're looking at a vector of only two elements.