# how to display Two-dimensional vector using auto keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, auto

**I used to display it using:**
'''
for(auto i: vector_name) cout << i;
'''
*but it doesn't work.*

Comment: Hi. Please [edit] the question and add the [C++] tag and explain what it does not work exactly mean. Also, use code formatting for code for better readability.

Comment: do you want to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928096/print-the-contents-of-a-2d-vector-using-auto ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily loop through the vector by its size, just use the size() member function:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    for(auto j: a[i]) cout<<j;
    cout<<endl;
}
```